# Rolling variance algorithm

Tags: algorithm, statistics, variance

I'm trying to find an efficient, numerically stable algorithm to calculate a rolling variance (for instance, a variance over a 20-period rolling window). I'm aware of the [Welford algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm) that efficiently computes the running variance for a stream of numbers (it requires only one pass), but am not sure if this can be adapted for a rolling window. I would also like the solution to avoid the accuracy problems discussed at the top of [this article](http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html) by John D. Cook. A solution in any language is fine.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Welford algorithm; I knew it was in Knuth but never knew the original source

Comment: Hello, what did you end up doing? Did you adapt Chan's algorithm? Btw, shouldn't kahan sum be able to overcome numerical instabilities when using the "naive" approach (keeping track the sums of the values and their squares)?

Comment: Another option is [Exponentially weighted moving variance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponentially_weighted_moving_variance_and_standard_deviation) which will yield different values compared to simple moving avg but doesn't require circular buffer hence more memory efficient.

Answer (score 37):

I have been dealing with the same issue.

Mean is simple to compute iteratively, but you need to keep the complete history of values in a circular buffer.

```
next_index = (index + 1) % window_size;    // oldest x value is at next_index, wrapping if necessary.

new_mean = mean + (x_new - xs[next_index])/window_size;
```

I have adapted Welford's algorithm and it works for all the values that I have tested with.

```
varSum = var_sum + (x_new - mean) * (x_new - new_mean) - (xs[next_index] - mean) * (xs[next_index] - new_mean);

xs[next_index] = x_new;
index = next_index;
```

To get the current variance just divide varSum by the window size: `variance = varSum / window_size;`

Comment: It might be slightly more stable to do `varSum += (x_new + x_old - mean - new_mean) * (x_new - x_old)`, where `x_old = xs[next_index]`, as you remove a potentially large `mean * new_mean` summand from the two items you subtract to update `varSum`. Other than that, this is the most correct of the answers here, and it's a pity it hasn't gotten more love.

Comment: To clarify Jaime's answer, he did some algebra taking DanS's `varSum` equation and distributing the multiplication. some terms cancel but you also have to perform the trick of adding in  `x_new * x_old  - x_new * x_old` to arrive at his result

Comment: Very late comment: Why are you diving by `window_size` and not `window_size-1`. In other words: Why aren't you using Bessel's correction. I notice that John D. Cook does include Bessel's correction in his running variance code.

Comment: couldn't you remove `varSum` entirely by just `variance += (x_new + x_old - mean - new_mean) * (x_new - x_old) / window_size`?

Answer (score 31):

I've run across this problem as well.  There are some great posts out there in computing the running cumulative variance such as John Cooke's *Accurately computing running variance* post and the post from Digital explorations, *Python code for computing sample and population variances, covariance and correlation coefficient*.  Just could not find any that were adapted to a rolling window.

The [Running Standard Deviations](http://subluminal.wordpress.com/2008/07/31/running-standard-deviations/#more-15) post by Subluminal Messages was critical in getting the rolling window formula to work.  Jim takes the power sum of the squared differences of the values versus Welford’s approach of using the sum of the squared differences of the mean.  Formula as follows:

> PSA today = PSA(yesterday) + (((x today * x today) - x yesterday)) / n
>
> - x = value in your time series
> - n = number of values you've analyzed so far.

But, to convert the Power Sum Average formula to a windowed variety you need tweak the formula to the following:

> PSA today = PSA yesterday + (((x today * x today) - (x yesterday * x Yesterday) / n
>
> - x = value in your time series
> - n = number of values you've analyzed so far.

You'll also need the Rolling Simple Moving Average formula:

> SMA today = SMA yesterday + ((x today - x today - n) / n
>
> - x = value in your time series
> - n = period used for your rolling window.

From there you can compute the Rolling Population Variance:

> Population Var today = (PSA today * n - n * SMA today * SMA today) / n

Or the Rolling Sample Variance:

> Sample Var today = (PSA today * n - n * SMA today * SMA today) / (n - 1)

I've covered this topic along with sample Python code in a blog post a few years back, [Running Variance](http://www.taylortree.com/2010/11/running-variance.html).

Hope this helps.

> Please note: I provided links to all the blog posts and math formulas
>   in Latex (images) for this answer.  But, due to my low reputation (<
>   10); I'm limited to only 2 hyperlinks and absolutely no images.  Sorry
>   about this.  Hope this doesn't take away from the content.

Comment: In this formula: `Population Var today = (PSA today * n - n * SMA today * SMA today) / n` - why not to remove `n`? `Population Var today = (PSA today - SMA today * SMA today)`.

Comment: Due to squaring samples in the formula, this algorithm exhibits the very numerical inaccuracy that OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: Yup, not a numerically stable approach. The closest thing to a correct answer is by @DanS below.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, here's a C# implementation https://gist.github.com/mattdot/d459b1cb15480fefd953841a1ac70be8

Comment: your line:  SMA today = SMA yesterday + ((x today - x today - n) / n  cant be right because x today - x today = 0

Answer (score 9):

If you prefer code over words (heavily based on DanS' post):
http://calcandstuff.blogspot.se/2014/02/rolling-variance-calculation.html

```
public IEnumerable RollingSampleVariance(IEnumerable data, int sampleSize)
{
    double mean = 0;
    double accVar = 0;

    int n = 0;
    var queue = new Queue(sampleSize);

    foreach(var observation in data)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(observation);
        if (n < sampleSize)
        {
            // Calculating first variance
            n++;
            double delta = observation - mean;
            mean += delta / n;
            accVar += delta * (observation - mean);
        }
        else
        {
            // Adjusting variance
            double then = queue.Dequeue();
            double prevMean = mean;
            mean += (observation - then) / sampleSize;
            accVar += (observation - prevMean) * (observation - mean) - (then - prevMean) * (then - mean);
        }

        if (n == sampleSize)
            yield return accVar / (sampleSize - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: for data = [0,1,2,4,7] and sampleSize = 2, this returns:  0.5, 0.5, 2, 4.5, 4.5.  I feel like the first number should be 0

Answer (score 7):

Actually Welfords algorithm can AFAICT easily be adapted to compute *weighted* Variance.
And by setting weights to -1, you should be able to effectively cancel out elements. I havn't checked the math whether it allows negative weights though, but at a first look it should!

I did perform a small experiment using [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/):

```
void testSlidingWindowVariance() {
MeanVariance mv = new MeanVariance(); // ELKI implementation of weighted Welford!
MeanVariance mc = new MeanVariance(); // Control.

Random r = new Random();
double[] data = new double[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i] = r.nextDouble();
}

// Pre-roll:
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  mv.put(data[i]);
}
// Compare to window approach
for (int i = 10; i < data.length; i++) {
  mv.put(data[i-10], -1.); // Remove
  mv.put(data[i]);
  mc.reset(); // Reset statistics
  for (int j = i - 9; j <= i; j++) {
    mc.put(data[j]);
  }
  assertEquals("Variance does not agree.", mv.getSampleVariance(),
    mc.getSampleVariance(), 1e-14);
}
}
```

I get around ~14 digits of precision compared to the exact two-pass algorithm; this is about as much as can be expected from doubles. Note that Welford *does* come at some computational cost because of the extra divisions - it takes about twice as long as the exact two-pass algorithm. If your window size is small, it may be much more sensible to actually recompute the mean and then in a second pass the variance *every* time.

I have added this experiment as unit test to ELKI, you can see the full source here: http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/browser/elki/trunk/test/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/math/TestSlidingVariance.java
it also compares to the exact two-pass variance.

However, on skewed data sets, the behaviour might be different. This data set obviously is uniform distributed; but I've also tried a sorted array and it worked.

**Update:** we published a paper with details on differentweighting schemes for (co-)variance:

> Schubert, Erich, and Michael Gertz. "**Numerically stable parallel computation of (co-) variance.**" Proceedings of the 30th International Conference on Scientific and Statistical Database Management. ACM, 2018. (Won the SSDBM best-paper award.)

This also discusses how weighting can be used to parallelize the computation, e.g., with AVX, GPUs, or on clusters.

Comment: Ported the ELKI MeanVarance.java class to JS, added a value buffer, and used weights of -1 to remove values.  I found result precision varies depending on how many values you run through the accumulator.  I was seeing ~12 digits of precision after running 1-10M values through it.  (I.e. "good enough")  Thanks for the tip on using -1 weights!

Comment: If you need higher precision than that, you will likely need to use Kahan summation or the Shewchuk algorithm. These use additional floats to store the lost digits, and hence can offer much higher precision. But the implementation gets much more messy and slower. For further details, see the reference I added to the post.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is old, but in case someone else is interested here follows the python code. It is inspired by [johndcook](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/standard_deviation/) blog post, @Joachim's, @DanS's code and @Jaime comments. The code below still gives small imprecisions for small data windows sizes. Enjoy.

```
from __future__ import division
import collections
import math


class RunningStats:
    def __init__(self, WIN_SIZE=20):
        self.n = 0
        self.mean = 0
        self.run_var = 0
        self.WIN_SIZE = WIN_SIZE

        self.windows = collections.deque(maxlen=WIN_SIZE)

    def clear(self):
        self.n = 0
        self.windows.clear()

    def push(self, x):

        self.windows.append(x)

        if self.n <= self.WIN_SIZE:
            # Calculating first variance
            self.n += 1
            delta = x - self.mean
            self.mean += delta / self.n
            self.run_var += delta * (x - self.mean)
        else:
            # Adjusting variance
            x_removed = self.windows.popleft()
            old_m = self.mean
            self.mean += (x - x_removed) / self.WIN_SIZE
            self.run_var += (x + x_removed - old_m - self.mean) * (x - x_removed)

    def get_mean(self):
        return self.mean if self.n else 0.0

    def get_var(self):
        return self.run_var / (self.WIN_SIZE - 1) if self.n > 1 else 0.0

    def get_std(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.get_var())

    def get_all(self):
        return list(self.windows)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Current window values: {}".format(list(self.windows))
```

Comment: thanks for the idea synthesis in python. I don't like how the size of windows become `WIN_SIZE - 1`in the case where the else block is entered. So if `WIN_SIZE` was 10 when `push` is called and we append, it's still 10 because of the deque constructor option used, then in the `else` block `popleft` reduces the size further to 9. So maybe `maxlen=WIN_SIZE + 1`? Or not use the `maxlen` option. Also, can drop the `n` variable and use `len(self.windows)`.

Comment: in the `get_var` method the denominator should be `self.n` or `len(self.windows)`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a divide and conquer approach that has `O(log k)`-time updates, where `k` is the number of samples. It should be relatively stable for the same reasons that pairwise summation and FFTs are stable, but it's a bit complicated and the constant isn't great.

Suppose we have a sequence `A` of length `m` with mean `E(A)` and variance `V(A)`, and a sequence `B` of length `n` with mean `E(B)` and variance `V(B)`. Let `C` be the concatenation of `A` and `B`. We have

```
p = m / (m + n)
q = n / (m + n)
E(C) = p * E(A) + q * E(B)
V(C) = p * (V(A) + (E(A) + E(C)) * (E(A) - E(C))) + q * (V(B) + (E(B) + E(C)) * (E(B) - E(C)))
```

Now, stuff the elements in a red-black tree, where each node is decorated with mean and variance of the subtree rooted at that node. Insert on the right; delete on the left. (Since we're only accessing the ends, a splay tree *might* be `O(1)`  amortized, but I'm guessing amortized is a problem for your application.) If `k` is known at compile-time, you could probably unroll the inner loop FFTW-style.

Comment: (Note: it's fine to compute q = 1 - p unless k is stupendously large.)

Comment: Okay, this is basically Chan et al.'s parallel algorithm as described on Wikipedia. That's what I get for not scrolling down...

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail how you would apply this algorithm to variance over a moving window? I'm slightly familiar with the Chan et al approach, but thought of it as a one-pass method for computing a single variance over an entire sample, with the added advantage that the problem can be broken into parts that are run in parallel.

Comment: Chan et al gave a way to compute statistics for a concatenation of parts given the statistics of the parts. The high-level idea is to maintain a collection of parts (actually just their statistics) such that any window is the concatenation of O(log k) parts. One way is with a balanced binary tree, but as Rex points out, this is overkill and we can just maintain statistics for aligned parts whose sizes are powers of two (e.g., [0, 1), [1, 2), [0, 2), [2, 3), [3, 4), [2, 4), [0, 4), etc.)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a minor addition to the excellent answer provided by DanS. The following equations are for removing the oldest sample from the window and updating the mean and variance. This is useful, for example, if you want to take smaller windows near the right edge of your input data stream (i.e. just remove the oldest window sample without adding a new sample).

```
window_size -= 1; % decrease window size by 1 sample
new_mean = prev_mean + (prev_mean - x_old) / window_size
varSum = varSum - (prev_mean - x_old) * (new_mean - x_old)
```

Here, x_old is the oldest sample in the window you wish to remove.

Answer (score 1):

I look forward to be proven wrong on this but I don't think this can be done "quickly." That said, a large part of the calculation is keeping track of the EV over the window which can be done easily.

I'll leave with the question: are you sure you *need* a windowed function? Unless you are working with very large windows it is probably better to just use a well known predefined algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I guess keeping track of your 20 samples, Sum(X^2 from 1..20), and Sum(X from 1..20) and then successively recomputing the two sums at each iteration isn't efficient enough?  It's possible to recompute the new variance without adding up, squaring, etc., all of the samples each time.

As in:

```
Sum(X^2 from 2..21) = Sum(X^2 from 1..20) - X_1^2 + X_21^2
Sum(X from 2..21) = Sum(X from 1..20) - X_1 + X_21
```

Comment: I believe this solution is susceptible to the stability problems mentioned in the link in my original post (http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html). In particular, when input values and large and their difference is small than the result could actually be negative. I will have no control over the input, so I would prefer to avoid this approach.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there anything you can say about the input? Intended use? Is it a problem that you can just throw more bits at (64-bit float, arbitary-precision arithmetic, etc.)?  Rounding errors go away if you trump the input in significant figures, no?

Comment: agreed -- this has stability issues. Imagine 1000 samples near 1,000,000.0, followed by 20 samples near zero.

Comment: @Jason S:  The rolling variance is what it is.  There might be a lot going on in the transition from 1 million to ~zero, but that's the nature of the beast.  That, and the first 980 of the 1000 ~1 million values are out of the picture when the change occurs anyway.  My comment suggested that if you had enough significant figures in your calculations, none of this would matter.

Comment: Input could really be anything. Value magnitude could certainly be in the trillions, and while the original data will only have accuracy to a few decimal points, users will be able to transform their data (for instance dividing by any scalar) before calculating the variance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another `O(log k)` solution: find squares the original sequence, then sum pairs, then quadruples, etc..  (You'll need a bit of a buffer to be able to find all of these efficiently.)  Then add up those values that you need to to get your answer.  For example:

```
|||||||||||||||||||||||||  // Squares
| | | | | | | | | | | | |  // Sum of squares for pairs
|   |   |   |   |   |   |  // Pairs of pairs
|       |       |       |  // (etc.)
|               |
   ^------------------^    // Want these 20, which you can get with
        |       |          // one...
    |   |       |   |      // two, three...
                    | |    // four...
   ||                      // five stored values.
```

<strike>Now you use your standard E(x^2)-E(x)^2 formula and you're done.</strike>  (Not if you need good stability for small sets of numbers; this was assuming that it was only accumulation of rolling error that was causing issues.)

That said, summing 20 squared numbers is *very* fast these days on most architectures.  If you were doing more--say, a couple hundred--a more efficient method would clearly be better.  But I'm not sure that brute force isn't the way to go here.

Comment: "use your standard E(x^2)-E(x)^2 formula" No, don't; it's not even remotely stable. Adapt one of the better algorithms.

Comment: @userOVER9000 - Why are you worried about stability over 20 items?  Cumulative errors that accumulate over millions of entries are a problem (especially when making a rolling window), but that's not the issue here.

Comment: I'm worried about it because it's an issue. Go read the Wikipedia article, and if you're still not convinced, try computing the variance of 20 iid samples of N(1, 1e-10).

Comment: I haven't seen this actually be an issue for any realistic data set with sensible units and origin, but fair enough, if that's what the OP wants...

Answer (score 1):

For only 20 values, it's trivial to adapt the method exposed [here](http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html) (I didn't say fast, though).

You can simply pick up an array of 20 of these `RunningStat` classes.

The first 20 elements of the stream are somewhat special, however once this is done, it's much more simple:

- when a new element arrives, clear the current `RunningStat` instance, add the element to all 20 instances, and increment the "counter" (modulo 20) which identifies the new "full" `RunningStat` instance
- at any given moment, you can consult the current "full" instance to get your running variant.

You will obviously note that this approach isn't really scalable...

You can also note that there is some redudancy in the numbers we keep (if you go with the `RunningStat` full class). An obvious improvement would be to keep the 20 lasts `Mk` and `Sk` directly.

I cannot think of a better formula using this particular algorithm, I am afraid that its recursive formulation somewhat ties our hands.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming here now, [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00180-021-01096-1)'s a reference containing the full derivation, with proofs, of DanS's answer and Jaime's related comment.

Answer (score 0):

DanS and Jaime's response in concise C.

```c
typedef struct {
    size_t n, i;
    float *samples, mean, var;
} rolling_var_t;

void rolling_var_init(rolling_var_t *c, size_t window_size) {
    size_t ss;

    memset(c, 0, sizeof(*c));
    c->n = window_size;
    c->samples = (float *) malloc(ss = sizeof(float)*window_size);
    memset(c->samples, 0, ss);
}

void rolling_var_add(rolling_var_t *c, float x) {
    float nmean;    // new mean
    float xold;     // oldest x
    float dx;

    c->i = (c->i + 1) % c->n;
    xold = c->samples[c->i];
    dx = x - xold;
    nmean = c->mean + dx / (float) c->n; // walk mean
    //c->var += ((x - c->mean)*(x - nmean) - (xold - c->mean) * (xold - nmean)) / (float) c->n;
    c->var += ((x + xold - c->mean - nmean) * dx) / (float) c->n;

    c->mean = nmean;
    c->samples[c->i] = x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a variable number of old values to remove from the sequence as its scale was not linear.  Below is code which only removes the last value from the sequence and calculates covariance updates without processing x_new.

x - old value x to be removed,
n - window size

```
newMeanX = (oldMeanX * n - x)/(n-1)
newVarX = (varX*n -(x-oldMeanX)*(x - newMeanX))/(n-1)
new_n = n-1
```

The actual problem I was trying to resolve was to remove oldest value from an online linear regression calculation.  Below is the full code for that including updates to covariance and mean of xy value.

```
var newN = lr.n - 1;

var newMeanX = (lr.meanX*lr.n - x)/newN;
var newMeanY = (lr.meanY*lr.n - y)/newN;
var newMeanXY = (lr.meanXY*lr.n - x*y)/newN;

lr.varX = (lr.varX*lr.n -(x - lr.meanX)*(x - newMeanX))/newN;
lr.varY = (lr.varY*lr.n -(y - lr.meanY)*(y - newMeanY))/newN;
lr.covXY = (lr.covXY*lr.n -(x - lr.meanX)*(y - newMeanY))/newN;

lr.meanX = newMeanX;
lr.meanY = newMeanY;
lr.meanXY = newMeanXY;

lr.n = newN;

lr.A = lr.covXY / lr.varX;
lr.B = lr.meanY - lr.A * lr.meanX;
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the first pWindowSize elements of means and varsUnnormalized using any correct method above.
Where if required

```
variance[i] = varsUnnormalized[i]/pWindowSize
```

Thereafter:

```
public void RollingSampleVarianceAlt( List<float> data, int pStartIdx, int pEndIdx, int pWindowSize, List<double> means, List<double> varsUnnormalized )
{
  for (int i = pStartIdx; i < pEndIdx; i++)
  {
    int old_idx = i - pWindowSize - 1;
    double new_mean = means[ i - 1 ] + (data[ i ] - data[ old_idx ])/(pWindowSize + 1);
    double varianceU = varsUnnormalized[ i - 1 ] + (data[ i ] + data[ old_idx ] - means[ i - 1 ] - new_mean)*(data[ i ] - data[ old_idx ]);
    means.Add( new_mean );
    varsUnnormalized.Add( varianceU );
  }
}
```

This lets you calculate for the new data elements since the last call of RollingSampleVarianceAlt without recomputing all means and variances up to that index.